# Using infinite floats in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, sqlite

In a Rails application using SQLite3 I'd like to use the float values `Float::INFINITY` and `-Float::INFINITY` in a model with a floating point attribute. Running `INSERT` queries using `Model.create!` this seems to work fine, since activerecord uses prepared statements in this case. However, when I try to update a record using `foo.save`, activerecord doesn't use a prepared stament and just puts the string `Infinity` right in the query, resulting in

```
SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: Infinity
```

Is there a way to work around this or do I need to resort to using strings in model/database?

Rails version `3.2.21`, SQLite3 version `1.3.10`

---

**Edit.** For now I changed the column type to `string` in the database migration and use

```
serialize :property, Float
```

to tell activerecord to store YAML-serialized floats in the database, allowing to store `Float::INFINITY` just fine.

Answer (score 2):

It's because `Float::INFINITY` in rails is defined as 1.0/0, that sqlite3 doesn't know what to do with it. You can use a very big number to define infinity like 9e999 as a replacement to the value you'll be saving to the database

Comment: No, [IEEE754](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point) explicitly defines float values named +∞ and −∞. You got it backwards, `1.0/0` is defined as `Float::INFINITY`. Setting an attribute to `9e999` results in the variable being set to `Float::INFINITY`, hence I get the same SQLite3 error.

Comment: Sorry about that. I'm not that familiar with float :) The idea is just to try a very big number as a replacement for infinity. Anyways, have you tried using `Float::MAX`? Just discovered it and knew that numbers bigger than this equals to infinity in ruby.